# App Store Connect: Problem with nested bundles - how to solve?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

I'm working through the validation process on an app for the App Store Connect. I've had to retrace my steps, and I'm trying to understand each problem.

```
The bundle at 'WordsBy2.app/Frameworks/Game.framework' contains disallowed nested bundles.
```

what does this mean, and how do I deal with it? Game.framework is the logic of the game I'm working on, and it in turn requires GRDB to run SQLite. Is this what this message is referring to?

Accompanying that is this:

```
The bundle at 'WordsBy2.app/Frameworks/Game.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
```

which I assume is related. And finally, there is

```
CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.github.groue.GRDB' under the iOS application 'WordsBy2.app'.
```

which sounds like somehow the GRDB package is being imported twice, but I can't see that that is happening – not that I really know what to look for....

This is the file layout:

[image: file layout]

Comment: A few ideas. First, have you uploaded this app - or any app - to App Store Connect before? I'm asking because of the basic process of archiving/uploading may be the issue. Next, about this framework. I have no issues with "self-created" frameworks at all. Is there any dependancies in it? How have you linked it to your project. (In this last one, I'm referring to what you have in the Xcode Project/General tab. What I do is create a workspace with two projects in it - one for the app and one for the framework.

Comment: hey @dfd: my current strategy is to have each framework imported but into the top of the main app. Then, I'm trying to make the db  a delegate of the game, so there's no need for the first to be internal to the second. It appears that frameworks that import frameworks is a problem.

To answer the question: my last upload to the App Store is ancient history, but I have uploaded this before, with the two frameworks that are causing grief excluded, and it was fine, but the app of course crashed.